# Visual Studio Code 'Vibrancy' Error, I can't download

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I can't download 'Vibrancy' in Visual Studio Code. I can download 'Vibrancy Continued' but not the original 'Vibrancy'. I did research on the internet but couldn't find anything useful. I don't know how to solve the error.

Search part:

[image: search part]

original vibrancy:

[image: original vibrancy]

vibrancy continued:

[image: vibrancy continued]